# PostgreSQL command does not list all schemas

Tags: postgresql

I'm wondering why `\d` only lists tables in the *public* schema?  I have another schema in the database, *sps*, but those tables are not listed...

```
# psql -p 5432 -U postgres -h localhost myDB
Password for user postgres:
psql (9.1.5)
Type "help" for help.

myDB=# \d
                 List of relations
Schema |            Name            |   Type   |  Owner
--------+----------------------------+----------+----------
public | tableA                     | table    | postgres
public | tableB                     | table    | postgres
public | tableC                     | table    | postgres
public | table_col_seq              | sequence | postgres
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change your `search_path`. In `psql` use `\dn` and then build your `search_path`:

```
SET search_path = schema1,schema2,public;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem i Intellij IDEA Database tab.

I got the soultion doing :
Data Sources and Drivers -> YOUR_DATA_SOURCE -> Schemas -> Check "All databases"